# How to make my bot send edited images in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I see a lot of bots there, sending custom images on welcome events,etc like koya bot sends a welcome image with the user's info printed on it .

like this:
[image]

I am not asking about on_member_join event or anything I am asking how can I make my bot do this , like I want the bot to print hello world on a image, How do I do that , what do I need for that?
Thanks!

Comment: You should look at the [pillow library](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). You can also find tutorials about [how to add text to an image](https://he-arc.github.io/livre-python/pillow/index.html) with pillow.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you just need a library for editing images. With Python you can use [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is the most famous.

Then you just have to retrieve the user's name and the other informations you want to show on the image via discord.py and then you can use pillow's methods to put the text on the background image or anything you want that you stocked in your bot's files.

Here is an example from the [pillow's doc](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
# get an image
base = Image.open("Pillow/Tests/images/hopper.png").convert("RGBA")

# make a blank image for the text, initialized to transparent text color
txt = Image.new("RGBA", base.size, (255,255,255,0))

# get a font
fnt = ImageFont.truetype("Pillow/Tests/fonts/FreeMono.ttf", 40)
# get a drawing context
d = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)

# draw text, half opacity
d.text((10,10), "Hello", font=fnt, fill=(255,255,255,128))
# draw text, full opacity
d.text((10,60), "World", font=fnt, fill=(255,255,255,255))

out = Image.alpha_composite(base, txt)

out.show()
```

And instead of `out.show()` you can save the image edited with `out.save('your-file-path.png')` and send it with `channel.send(file=discord.File('your-file-path.png'))`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out ImageMagick's Draw - add shapes or text to an image https://imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/#text

Maybe you can use [Wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/), a ctypes-based simple ImageMagick binding for Python, here's the documentation on draw text https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.2/guide/draw.html#texts